# componentDidMount() not being called when react component is mounted

Tags: reactjs

I've been attempting to fetch some data from a server and for some odd reason `componentDidMount()` is not firing as it should be. I added a `console.log()` statement inside of `componentDidMount()` to check if it was firing. I know the request to the server works as it should As I used it outside of react and it worked as it should.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      obj: {}
    };
  };

  getAllStarShips () {
    reachGraphQL('http://localhost:4000/', `{
     allStarships(first: 7) {
       edges {
         node {
           id
           name
           model
           costInCredits
           pilotConnection {
             edges {
               node {
                 ...pilotFragment
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
    }
    fragment pilotFragment on Person {
     name
     homeworld { name }
   }`, {}). then((data) => {
     console.log('getALL:', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
      this.setState({
        obj: data
      });
   });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Check to see if firing')
    this.getAllStarShips();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('state:',JSON.stringify(this.state.obj, null, 2));
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React-Reach!</h1>
      <p>{this.state.obj.allStarships.edges[1].node.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

}

render(
  <App></App>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Are you using ReactDOM.render? You may have problems with rendering the component with the original state. Try providing the full this.state.obj.allStarships.edges[1].node.name to the original state (or be a little safer in its usage in your render method).

Comment: You should have un TypeError while your component is rendering the first time because `allStarships` is `undefined`. If so, this may crash your app and prevents runtime execution. Just a guess.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Jim Pedid, I am using react-dom.

Comment: I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edges' of undefined`

Comment: Right, so make sure that you have that property in the state you set in the constructor (or don't blindly use a.b without first checking that a exists.)

Just making sure you're using reactdom to avoid any issues.

Comment: this line is where the problem is: <p>{this.state.obj.allStarships.edges[1].node.name}</p>

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work! If you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it correct. @JimPedid

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue here is that the render method is crashing, because the following line is generating an error

```
<p>{this.state.obj.allStarships.edges[1].node.name}</p>
```

Fix this to not use this.state.obj.allStarships.edges[1].node.name directly, unless you can guarantee that each receiver is defined.

Answer (score 6):

**Check your component's key**

Another thing that will cause this to happen is if your component does not have a key. In React, the key property is used to determine whether a change is just new properties for a component or if the change is a new component.

React will only unmount the old component and mount a new one if the key changed. If you're seeing cases where componentDidMount() is not being called, make sure your component has a unique key.

With the key set, React will interpret them as different components and handle unmounting and mounting.

**Example Without a Key:**

```
<SomeComponent prop1={foo} />
```

**Example with a Key**

```
const key = foo.getUniqueId()
<SomeComponent key={key} prop1={foo} />
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this was exactly what was wrong with my component not being updated. I searched for an answer for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Also check that you don't have more than one componentDidMount if you have a component with a lot of code. It's a good idea to keep lifecycle methods near the top after the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue (componentDidMount() not being called) because my component was adding an attribute to the component state in the constructor, but not in the Component declaration. It caused a runtime failure.

Problem:

```
class Abc extends React.Component<props, {}> {
    this.state = { newAttr: false }; ...
```

Fix:

```
class Abc extends React.Component<props, {newAttr: boolean}> {
    this.state = { newAttr: false }; ...
```